# How to insert multiple custom properties in one action using the google drive SDK

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I've read the Drive SDK reference manual and use the information from the url below to insert a set of custom properties to a file on the drive:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/properties/insert

During this I have to call the execute command multiple times (once for each insert):

```
Property newProperty1 = new Property();
newProperty1.setKey(key);
newProperty1.setValue(value);

Property newProperty2 = new Property();
newProperty2.setKey(key);
newProperty2.setValue(value);

gDriveService.properties().insert(fileId, newProperty1).execute();
gDriveService.properties().insert(fileId, newProperty2).execute();
```

I'm looking for a way to insert multiple custom properties at once so that I only have to call execute only once (which should improve performance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could batch your requests as described here https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Batch

NB. I'm having major issues with batching more than 20 inserts. Hopefully if (a) your batches are smaller and (b) inserting properties doesn't have the same issues as inserting files, you should be OK.